# ReturnUrl causes error when user is already logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a site with a regular Login.aspx page. However, sometimes the user's appear to have bookmarked something like:

```
login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fTaco%2fResources%2fVideo%2Burrito.swf
```

I get a bunch of null reference exceptions in the following scenario. The user logs into the url listed above with a ReturnUrl. After navigating to the content, they hit Back because they probably didn't want to go specifically to that page. Then they're back on the login page and re-log in. This throws an error when it tries to go again to the ReturnUrl.

How can I simply redirect a logged in user to my Default page or check if the user is logged in on page load of the login page to then redirect them?

EDIT:
I'm realizing that my page load event on the login page doesn't fire upon hitting the back button because it is cached. I'll try:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Comment: The above edit fixed it for me. Kind of a workaround but setting noCache doesn't have any user experience issues in this particular project.

Answer (score 0):

Setting:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

along with:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Taco.aspx");
            }
```

on the Page_Load event for my Login.aspx page did the trick.